# Entity Framework OnModelCreating missing mapping

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am using EF4.3 code first and fluent mapping.

I have:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating
```

being executed on application startup.  This is done via Windsor DI as my RepositoryContext is created.

When my views come to use the model eg

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CostPrice)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CostPrice)
    </div>
```

any attribute on the model is reflected in the validation, but any mapping from OnModelCreating is now lost.

I don't know where to start debugging, so I can't paste the code up without including a large cunk of the application.   How do I start investigating?

Answer (score 1):

Validations specified with attributes are recognized by MVC; validations specified in EF initialization code are not, because they aren't accessible at all by MVC.

Only possible solution to avoid repetition: move validations to model attributes.

Comment: I think the fluent API can be used to specify attributes:
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().Property(t => t.Name).IsRequired();

Comment: That is not an attribute. That is a configuration value that EF gets, but MVC has no way of knowing you've configured EF that way. [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) are attributes.